# Intergration tests for fullCalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, fullcalendar, bdd

I love fullCalendar. Its an awesome plugin. However one thing that I have found hard is testing. I am using rails, cucumber, capybera and selenium. I spent a good part of yesterday using the selenium IDE and could not for the life of me get selenium to simulate a click on fullcalendar's interface. I was wondering if anyone else has this problem or has got a testing plan outlined for fullCalendar?

Answer (score 1):

i was working on fullCalendar for the last couple of days and i have some rspecs if that would help out.

you can check what i have at https://github.com/mzararagoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube